# Elegant way to borrow and return a mutable reference in Rust

Tags: reference, rust, mutable, borrowing

I'm trying to return a mutable reference after doing some operation on it. This is best explained by a piece of code:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum Value {
    Null,
    Array(Vec<Value>),
}

impl Value {
    pub fn new() -> Value {
        Value::Array(Vec::new())
    }

    pub fn push<'a, T> (&'a mut self, value: T) -> Option<&'a mut Value>
    where T:Into<Value> {
        let temp = match *self {
            Value::Array(ref mut vec) => {
                vec.push(value.into());
                true
            },
            _ => false,
        };
        if temp {
            Some(self)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn push_test() {
    let mut val = Value::new();
    val.push(Value::Null);
    assert!(val == Value::Array(vec![Value::Null]));
}
```

The play version is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9e1436c862d0a4c5b1096343720c33d3&version=stable&backtrace=0). The workaround with boolean values is because I would be borrowing multiple times if I return `Some(self)` from within the `match` block. Is there an elegant way to implement the `push` function without using boolean values? If its possible to retain the function signature then its a bonus. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The workaround with boolean values is because I would be borrowing multiple times if I return `Some(self)` from within the match block

Another option is to replace `self` temporally, so `v` can take the ownership of the vector (avoiding the borrow). After adding the new item to `v`, we reconstruct the `self` value:

```
// the lifetime 'a can be omitted
pub fn push<T>(&mut self, value: T) -> Option<&mut Value>
    where T: Into<Value>
{
    // replace put Value::Null on self and return the old value
    match ::std::mem::replace(self, Value::Null) {
        Value::Array(mut v) => {
            v.push(value.into());
            *self = Value::Array(v);
            Some(self)
        },
        _ => None,
    }
}
```